# Alternative to gpedit.msc for Windows Home editions?

Tags: windows, group-policy

Is there an alternative to `gpedit.msc` for "Home" versions of Windows (ie: Vista Home Premium)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The gpedit.msc is basically a front-end for various registry settings.

Microsoft published a document called [Group Policy Settings Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250) which "displays the Group Policy settings in the Administrative Templates folder and the registry entries that they change".

You can open the Registry Editor and change the key listed in the table.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  (And I am now considering writing a front end to these keys, but manually regeditting them will work for now.)

Comment: @Albic, Is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815238.aspx the full list?

Comment: @Pacerier: It appears it's not the full list. I couldn't find the *"Always use custom login background"* item under the `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon` section as described in the How-To Geek article [How to Set a Custom Logon Screen Background](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/).

Comment: Additionally, @MiffTheFox: The page (and its links) do not specify in detail what values must be written to the registry; it only states the registry key and the entry which holds the value. You'll therefore need a working version of Group Policy Editor to test the values being written to the registry. Kindly send me a message if you decide to undertake this task. I will be glad to contribute.

Comment: This is the Windows 2000 list, and is heavily outdated. The current version can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=25250).

Comment: @AlexEssilfie: see [my answer to the "duplicate" question](https://superuser.com/a/1195862/240295) for a site which also has all the values for the entries. Also, the How-To Geek article has a typo: it should be _"Always use custom log**o**n background"_, as their screenshot shows.

Comment: I improved the edit suggestion to be https, because the edit that was in the queue, wasn't https and thus would have failed the current requirement of all links being https.  I also pointed the link to the en-us link, since the original link, was en-us not en-au

Answer (score 2):

this site offers free gpedit for win10 add on... https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/
I've not checked code so unsure how safe it is but sounds good to me, maybe someone can verify the code?

Comment: more info on same thing here: http://windowsreport.com/install-group-policy-editor-windows-10-home/

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: No need. The instructions are already in my answer to [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/q/1018145)

Comment: There is also the alternative [`Policy Plus`](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus).