# Users and Groups management on 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, networking, permissions, user-accounts, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local Users and Groups Management on Windows 7 Home?](https://superuser.com/questions/361251/local-users-and-groups-management-on-windows-7-home)

I recently upgraded my home PC from Windows XP Pro, to Windows 7 Home Premium.

Since Local Users and Groups is blocked on Home Premium, I can't figure out how to manage groups, or even do anything even *slightly* advanced to users (basically, create/group/picture is it). Net localgroup, net users, net etc, doesn't seem to work - getting "system error 5".

While I'm on the topic, I cant activate (what was once) "Local Security Policy"...

Looking for any help, advice, or even a new direction because things are different in Windows 7.

---

To clarify, I'm looking to do some of the following, which were simply back in XP-land:

- remote user only (i.e. no local logon)
- Grant special privileges for specific user
- grant access to e.g. C$ share for specific remote user
- create custom groups for users, to be able to separate privileges of say, my wife's from my kids
- define quite specifically what each user can do (beyond just standard users)
- Harden OS (hmm, I guess maybe what I'm looking for is a security hardening guide for 7?)

Comment: Related: [Alternative to gpedit.msc for Windows Home editions?](http://superuser.com/questions/40143/alternative-to-gpedit-msc-for-vista-home-premium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to use net commands on windows 7 home premium and I do not get system error 5. Have you tried running cmd as administrator and then typing the net commands?

A registry reference might also help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815238.aspx

Comment: D'oh, tried everything else running as admin, forgot cmdline utils dont elevate... Still, limit in what I can do with net use... still looking for complete(r) solution? e.g. security policy... Thanks.