# Enable Local Users and Groups in Basic Edition? Or Registry Table for it?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-registry, group-policy

I have a Basic version of Windows 8.1 (home version; premium; whatever). I *do not* have a corporate or business version. I know that Group Policy Editor is just a fancy interface for this [Group Policy Registry Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815238.aspx).

However, is there:

A) A Local Users and Groups (lusrgmr) registry table equivalent?
B) A registry hack to force *enable* lusrmgr?

Regarding question *B*, I tried adding the string *Restrict_Run* and modifying it between 0 and 1, and no matter what, it just says that Local Users and Groups has been restricted. I add it to *HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MMC{5D6179C8-17EC-11D1-9AA9-00C04FD8FE93}*

I tried a DWORD as well, and that won't work. Is there some other string or DWORD that I can put in to force enable it?

Otherwise, a registry table equivalent would be fantastic. I just can't find one.

Comment: Wooo! So far, I found [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/202251-user-group-create-new-delete.html). I can create the group using command prompt (cmd), but I can't figure out how to assign rights. So I will have to figure that out next (unless someone knows how). Then I will just use control userpasswords2 (type that into run), and change the user group manually that way.

Comment: What are you trying to use `lusrgmr.msc` to accomplish exactly?  Are you simply trying to enable the `Local Users and Groups` snap-in?

Comment: I am attempting to re-enact the old ability that Power Users had (but don't anymore; even on corporate editions of windows) to be a Standard User, but with the ability to install programs. [I haven't quite figured out the answer yet](http://superuser.com/questions/879449/how-do-i-allow-a-standard-user-to-install-programs), but I'm getting close. Even if that means somehow getting lusrgmr to work so I can create my own modified user group.

Comment: So your actual question is how to create new users and new groups either without the "Local Users and Groups" snap-in or enable the snap-in without the group policy editor which allows you to do that.

Comment: If that is the case then [this](http://superuser.com/questions/361251/local-users-and-groups-management-on-windows-7-home) should explain how to do it.  You need an `Administrator` account to setup everything obviously.

Comment: Ramhound, that is exactly what I am trying to do (either enable the snapin to create new groups or somehow create groups without the snapin).

Comment: That means the question I linked to contains the how to do that.

Comment: Yes. I had to install ntrights.exe and start assigning rights to the group I created. I am going to post the answer to my question as soon as I completely get this figured out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it without the snap-in OR the registry. I need to use elevated command prompt, `net localgroup` `ntrights` and also setting permissions on the c drive for my newly created group. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/879449/how-do-i-allow-a-standard-user-to-install-programs) for my more in depth answer.