# Enable password-blank Run As on Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, windows, runas

Is there a registry setting I can change to apply this fix from http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=303846?

> You can disable blank password restrictions by using a policy. To
>   locate and change this policy: Click Start, point to Run, type
>   gpedit.msc, and then click OK to start the Group Policy Editor. Open
>   Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local
>   Policies\Security Options\Accounts: Limit local account use of blank
>   passwords to console logon only. Double-click Limit local account use
>   of blank passwords to consol logon only. Click Disabled, and then
>   click OK. Quit Group Policy Editor.

I want to Run As to a different user with a blank password, but I can't. I get this message a lot with remote access too. How can I change it in Home Premium?

(I just saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/40143/alternative-to-gpedit-msc-for-vista-home-premium) but the setting's not in the list.)

Comment: I think you need to state the specific problem you are trying to solve and all the OSs involved.

Comment: @Moab: I want to run a program as a different user, a user who doesn't have a password, on Windows 7 Home Premium. Thanks for the answer, I'll try it soon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this, it may be for XP but suggestion to use regshot on a Pro Windows 7 PC to capture the registry change may solve it for you

> Take a look at this registry key which may disable it. I believe when set to 
>   zero as shown.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\limitblankpassworduse:
0x00000000
```

> I use a free program called Regshot to do comparisons of the registry before 
>   and after such a change. There are other programs that may be a bit easier 
>   to use but for the price and the fact that it does not have to be installed 
>   make Regshot a neat utility to have.

http://www.snapfiles.com/get/regshot.html --- Regshot.

[Source of Information](http://forum.soft32.com/win3/registry-key-blank-passwd-ftopict51477.html)

I checked my Windows 7 Pro gpedit, that group policy location does not exist, they must have changed it in Windows 7 for security reasons.

Comment: That's good news, so it was the registry hack?

Comment: Yes, it was the registry hack. Good thing it still exists. (Now I have the added bonus of a computer-universal iTunes, too!)