# User restriction policy when creating a scheduled task

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, task-scheduler

I have a problem when creating a scheduled task on Windows7 Pro SP1. The task is supposed to run a .bat file on system startup. This is to happen before user logon. When i click 'OK' to finish creating the task this is the error that i get:

```
Error has occurred for task 'TaskName'. Error message: User account restriction error. The possible reasons are that blank passwords not allowed, or that a policy restriction has been enforced.
```

The computer is on a remote location and already delivered to the client so I don't have full access. My only way of accessing it is via TeamViewer. The user that is logged in on the computer at the time when I access it via TeamViewer is 'admin'. I believe that the user does not have a password. That pointed me in this direction : [Enable password-blank Run As on Home Premium?](https://superuser.com/questions/342680/enable-password-blank-run-as-on-home-premium)

However, when i create the same task with the option 'Run only when user is logged on', the task is created succesfuly. That led me to the conclusion that the upper link may not be so relevant.

I would love to try and avoid registry editing as proposed in the aforementioned link since the computer is practically not mine. But if that is the solution and a last resort, I will use it.

Do you have a different solution for this problem or is registry editing the only solution (if it in fact is a solution)?

Comment: Could you temporarily give the remote user a password, schedule the task, and then remove it?

Comment: @martineau Did not even think of this. For now i just added a password. But yes, if I remove it, the task is still active. Please do write this as an answer so I can accept it. So simple :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work around the problem, you might be able to just give the remote user a password long enough for you to schedule the task, and then remove it when you're through. Don't really know if it'll work because I'm not familiar with TeamViewer.

Comment: As mentioned, works like a charm

Answer (score 5):

Check the "Do not store password", worked for me.

[image: Picture]