# My Windows edition has no "secpol.msc". How can I edit security policies?

Tags: windows, command-line

It seems that some Windows editions don't include the GUI **secpol.msc** tool.
I would like to change some data at **Local Security Policy**, like, for example, *Create a token object*.
How can I do that?
All I have found until now is the *secedit* command-line tool, but it allows only export/import of a complete tree, not changing specific parameters.
Command-line method prefered, please, but GUI allowed too.

Comment: Which edition of Windows are you on?

Comment: You can't.  You would have to attach them to a domain in order to do this.

Comment: You could try the solution given here: http://superuser.com/questions/40143/alternative-to-gpedit-msc-for-windows-home-editions

Comment: I have found this problem on some editions of Windows 8, Windows 7 and Windows XP, the less featured.

Comment: Well, I can not really think that this question is duplicated: **gpedit.msc** is not exactly **secpol.msc**, so it could be useful to remain in the SuperUser forum a thread with this title.

Comment: @JSanchez , your solution (the *Group Policy Registry Table*) seems not to have anything about the word "token", so I must suppose that is not a complete replacement for "secpol.msc". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: **gpedit.msc**: under *Computer Configuration* --> *Windows Configuration* --> *Security policies*.
By default it's only installed on Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate editions. But you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/) to install it on other version.

[image]

Comment: The answer is correct. It is logical that the **Group Policies Editor** should include the **Security Policies** tool, but it wasn't obvious for me. Thanks, @chaput .