# Automatically start task when computer is locked in Windows 7 Home Edition

Tags: windows-7, windows, automation, scheduled-tasks

I found [a tutorial](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Tutorial:_Automatically_mine_when_computer_is_locked_on_Windows) on how to start a task automatically when my computer locks, which required that I use secpol.msc.  Unfortunately, this utility is unavailable in Windows 7 Home edition.  I went to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25250) to determine how to access this task by editing the registry, and found this entry: `Audit Policy security settings are not registry keys.`

I'm trying to use task scheduler to accomplish this automation, but I am open to alternatives.

tl;dr: I tried some things, but automatically starting tasks on custom event firings is not possible using task scheduler in Windows 7 Home Edition.

Comment: already answer : http://superuser.com/questions/730936/my-windows-edition-has-no-secpol-msc-how-can-i-edit-security-policies/730943#730943

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but I think listing all the steps here might be useful to someone somewhere.

1. [Install a group policy editor](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/)
2. Consult [this spreadsheet](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25250) to determine which policy corresponds to the one found in secpol.msc.
3. Schedule tasks as you would normally.